# MonacaでのOAuth.ioについて

Tags: javascript, monaca, twitter

現在Monacaを利用してTwitterのクライアントを作成しています。
OAuth.ioを利用してOAuth認証を行おうとしているのですが、
OAuth.popup()を行った際ブラウザにて

> "Cannot find hostname in file:/// from static
>   code: InvalidHeader
>   message: Cannot find hostname in file:/// from static"

という表示をされて認証画面に進むことができません。
これはどういうことなのでしょうか？

現時点でのコードを載せておきます

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['onsen' , 'twitterApp.services']);
```

controller.js

```
app.controller('TwitterController', function($scope, $q, twitterService) {

    $scope.tweets; //array of tweets

    twitterService.initialize();

    //using the OAuth authorization result get the latest 20 tweets from twitter for the user
    $scope.refreshTimeline = function() {
        twitterService.getLatestTweets().then(function(data) {
            $scope.tweets = data;
        });
    }

    //when the user clicks the connect twitter button, the popup authorization window opens
    $scope.connectButton = function() {
        twitterService.connectTwitter().then(function() {
            if (twitterService.isReady()) {
                //if the authorization is successful, hide the connect button and display the tweets
                $('#connectButton').fadeOut(function(){
                    $('#getTimelineButton, #signOut').fadeIn();
                    $scope.refreshTimeline();
                });
            }
        });
    }

    //sign out clears the OAuth cache, the user will have to reauthenticate when returning
    $scope.signOut = function() {
        twitterService.clearCache();
        $scope.tweets.length = 0;
        $('#getTimelineButton, #signOut').fadeOut(function(){
            $('#connectButton').fadeIn();
        });
    }

    //if the user is a returning user, hide the sign in button and display the tweets
    if (twitterService.isReady()) {
        $('#connectButton').hide();
        $('#getTimelineButton, #signOut').show();
        $scope.refreshTimeline();
    }

});
```

services.js

```
angular.module('twitterApp.services', []).factory('twitterService', function($q) {

    var authorizationResult = false;

    return {
        initialize: function() {
            //initialize OAuth.io with public key of the application
            OAuth.initialize('*************************', {cache:true});
            //try to create an authorization result when the page loads, this means a returning user won't have to click the twitter button again
            authorizationResult = OAuth.create('twitter');
        },
        isReady: function() {
            return (authorizationResult);
        },
        connectTwitter: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            OAuth.popup('twitter', {cache:true}, function(error, result) { //cache means to execute the callback if the tokens are already present
                if (!error) {
                    authorizationResult = result;
                    deferred.resolve();
                } else {
                    //do something if there's an error
                }
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        },
        clearCache: function() {
            OAuth.clearCache('twitter');
            authorizationResult = false;
        },
        getLatestTweets: function () {
            //create a deferred object using Angular's $q service
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var promise = authorizationResult.get('/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json').done(function(data) { //https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/home_timeline
                //when the data is retrieved resolved the deferred object
                deferred.resolve(data)
            });
            //return the promise of the deferred object
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: アプリのURLを使ってリダイレクトか何かをしようとしたが、MonacaアプリのURLは `file://...` なのでエラーに、といった状況に見えます。[Cordovaプラグイン版のSDK](https://github.com/oauth-io/oauth-phonegap)を試していただくか、あるいはOAuth.ioは諦めてjsOAuthなどを検討された方がよいかもしれません。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。Monacaアプリの仕様上どうしてもエラーになってしまうのですね。。。Cordovaプラグインの方を追加する方法も考えましたが、スタンダードプランではCordovaプラグインを追加できないので現状この方法ではできなそうですね。
諦めてサンプルで使用されているjsOAuthや他のOAuthのコンポーネントを利用したいと思います。